# Running JavaScript code on PDF pages on my domain?

Tags: javascript

I it possible to run javascript code on for example: `mydomain.com/pdf/pdf-example.pdf`?

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

My intention is to add live chat code so that we can help customers while they are looking at the PDF

Comment: For an answer you should really state your intention

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to `iframe` the PDF into the page, and put the support chat over it? Many (most?) browsers can display PDFs now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to render a PDF file onto a standard HTML page. So instead of linking directly to the PDF file, you would create a new HTML page, where you would embed the pdf.js viewer, as well as any additional custom Javascript. [Here](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) is a demo. The downside to pdf.js, is [browser support](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#faq-support) is limited.

Another option is [pdfobject](http://pdfobject.com/), which enables you to embed PDF's within pages. This uses the browsers  native PDF viewer for rendering.